# Handling Orientation change with ViewPager + FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I'm having trouble handling screen orientation change with ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter. It works fine on application startup but the fragments inside the viewpager are not visible after orientation change (maybe lost). How do I fix this issue.
Following is the structure of my activity:
[image]

edit:
This is the manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:name="com.test.myapp.NetworkManager.TBVolleyInstance"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RouterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

FragmentPagerAdapter implementation:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new Fragment1();
    case 1:
        return new Fragment2();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position){ 
    return(1.0f); 
}
```

}

Comment: try to follow this guide https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little late but I just fixed this exact problem on my app. There are two solutions.

1) You have to use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` rather than a `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Or

2) If your ViewPager is wrapped in a Fragment (like your image shows), then when you create the ViewPager's adapter, you have to use `getChildFragmentManager()` rather than `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Hope this helps someone out as this took me an entire day of torture to figure this out.

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() was the key !

Comment: getChildFragmentManager(), you are awesome.